# Помогите с .htaccess и регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Ребят, помогите сделать редирект. 
Есть старые страницы каталога типа

```
example.com/catalog/item
```

Нужно сделать

```
example.com/item
```

Причем, если там, перед item встречается view, редирект отклоняется. 
То есть если

```
example.com/catalog/view/item
```

то адрес сохраняется.
У меня есть такое, но в некоторых случаях оно почему-то работать отказывается

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^view].*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Проблема в том, что если адрес такой

```
example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty/
```

то не работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

@saidolim хорошо. Смотрите, если у меня есть правило

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^view].*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

строка

```
http://example.com/catalog/view/theme
```

то её не должно никак обрабатывать. 
А если поступает строка

```
http://example.com/catalog/peptids_and_gr
```

то она обрабатывается и становится такой:

```
http://example.com/peptids_and_gr
```

Также должно быть и со строкой

```
http://example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty
```

Но почему-то ничего не происходит, хотя view после catalog нету. 
То есть, как я понимаю, если бы было

```
http://example.com/catalog/view/injektsionnye_preparaty
```

То тогда да, не прошло бы.. А тут обе эти строки не проходят

```
http://example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty
http://example.com/catalog/view/injektsionnye_preparaty
```

Что скажете?

Comment: Ой, простите, товарищ @Saidolim, не так составил пункт с view. Там на входе идет адрес, к примеру такой:

    example.com/catalog/view/item

Comment: Спасибо, @saidolim за ресурс для тестирования. Там мой код работает как надо. Почему на сервере может так неверно обрабатывать? Оно просто оставляет example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty/ и не делает с ним ничего..

Comment: можете показать полный код .htaccess ?

Comment: @saidolim А, нет, простите, ошибся, на этом тестировщике не сработало. Адрес на входе example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty/test_propionat , правило: RewriteRule ^catalog/([^view/].*)$ $1 [R=301,L]. Не хочет обрабатывать. Подскажите почему.

Comment: в вопросе `example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty/test_propionat` не было. покажите полный код и все обработки что нужно

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev Прочитайте правки внизу исходного вопроса

Comment: проверьте код который я поправил. теперь точно работает. Проверьте

Comment: Даа да да, спасибо огромное!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему просто не пробовали

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^catalog/view/(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

---

для тестирование http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Тест 1

```
http://example.com/catalog/item
=>
http://example.com/item
```

Тест 2

```
http://example.com/catalog/view/item
=>
http://example.com/catalog/view/item
```

Тест 3

```
http://example.com/catalog/injektsionnye_preparaty/
=>
http://example.com/injektsionnye_preparaty/
```